# I cannot retrieve data from firebase database using async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Angular 4 by watching the Udemy course of Mosh Hamedani. When building a list of categories in his app, he used the AngularFireBase method  'list'. I was trying to duplicate the code, but the async pipe does not show any results. I have tried to do my research but in vain.

I have also read that some things were changed (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md). However, my app does not seem to find the valueChanges method at all. Also, the db.list method returns the value I need according to the VS Code Intellicence.

class where I return categories

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

getCategories() {
     return this.db.list('/categories');
}

}
```

class from which I try to use categories in the html template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
}
```

html template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
        {{ c.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

please help because I am desperate here

Comment: One additional remark - I have to use rather old versions of everything. From package.json:
    "angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "firebase": "4.2.0",

Comment: good lort angular looks awful. it's dead simple to interact with firebase via standard javascript. looking at the provided angular code, i'm guessing you must define what `db` is. You need to initialize firebase, then you have to provide a reference to what you want to get/fetch.

Comment: It is initialized in another component. I have pasted only the 3 relevant component to the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, 2 weeks of debugging and thinking of workarounds. Angular 4.0.0 works fine with   angularfire2 4.0.0-rc.1 and firebase 4.2.0. The problem was with my structure of firebase database - I nested the categories field one additional time. Jesus.